# Why is it not echo'ing when $i reaches 4?

Tags: php

The code below is meant to be creating a new row every 4 tiles, but it is not. This is based around Bootstrap and when it starts a new row the tiles will continue from the left. This is what is happening at the moment http://www.baboonhut.com/

```
<?php
$dir = 'resources/';
$i = 1;
$dirs = glob($dir.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
array_multisort(
    array_map('authormodified', $dirs),
    SORT_NUMERIC,
    SORT_DESC,
    $dirs
);
function authormodified($dir) {
    return filemtime($dir.'/author.txt');
}

foreach($dirs as $resdir) {
    $i++;
    $resdir = str_replace($dir, '', $resdir);
    $filename = 'resources/'. $resdir .'/author.txt';
    $hit_count = @file_get_contents('resources/'. $resdir .'/count.txt');

if(!$i%4)
    echo '</div><div class="row demo-tiles">';

    echo "
<div class=\"span3\">
<div class=\"tile\">
<img src=\"resources/". $resdir ."/thumbnail.png\" class=\"img-rounded\">
<h3 class=\"tile-title\">". $resdir ."</h3>
<span class=\"label label-warning\"><i class=\"icon-calendar\"></i> " . date("jS F y", filectime($filename)); echo "</span> <span class=\"label label-info\"><i class=\"icon-download\"></i> "; echo $hit_count; echo "</span>
<p>"; echo file_get_contents('resources/'. $resdir .'/description.txt'); echo "</p>
<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block\" href=\"http://www.baboonhut.com/resources/" . $resdir ."/\">More Information</a>
</div>
</div>
"
;
}
?>
```

Comment: Where's an `else` clause to handle it when $i % 4 is 0? (e.g. when $I is 4 or 8 or 12, etc)? You only have code for when $i % 4 is 1, 2 or 3

Comment: He doesn't need one for what he is doing. The second echo will print regardless what the `if` does. The `else` case here would be empty, and as such, can be left out.

Comment: Femaref is correct, it shouldn't be needed here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). `!` has higher priority than `%`. You need

```
if(!($i % 4)) {
    echo '...';
}
```

Without the brackets, your condition is evaluated as if  `((!$i) % 4)` which is false for all `$i != 0`